# Do the mutable Collection.empty methods violate Scala's zero-argument naming convention?

Tags: scala, collections, naming-conventions, side-effects

[This](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map$@empty[A,B]:scala.collection.mutable.Map[A,B]) is how the `.empty` method is declared in the `scala.collection.mutable.Map` object in Scala 11.5:

```
def empty[A, B]: Map[A, B]
```

Shouldn't this method have empty parentheses, like this?

```
def empty[A, B](): Map[A, B]
```

The page on Scala's [naming conventions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#parentheses) suggests, without saying it explicitly, that omitting the parentheses on a 0-arity method is the convention for pure-functional code, and including empty parentheses means that the method has a side-effect. (I think I've run into an error message that's more explicit about this.)

The mutable `.empty` method has a side-effect, since you can distinguish the results of separate calls to `.empty`. Shouldn't it get empty parentheses, even though its mate in `immutable.Map` doesn't?

Regarding my own code, is there a special naming convention I should follow when creating and returning a mutable object from a 0-arity method?

Answer (score 6):

No. `scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[A, B]` does not have any side effects. It is a method that returns a new `mutable.Map[A, B]` every time you call it.

`mutable.Map#empty` (the method in the trait itself) also returns a new empty `mutable.Map` of the same type. It does not empty the collection (like it appears it might), so there are no side effects.

See [the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3fafbc204fe2ce94e64c6893e74e3855dc875ae8/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Map.scala#L61) if you're unsure.

Comment: My understanding is that if, when you replace a second call to a function with a variable holding the result of the first call, the result of the program changes, then the function performs a side-effect. Something must be different every time you call `.empty`, which is necessary so you can later modify one empty Map without affecting the other. Or am I following a non-standard naming convention for "side-effect"? :) I got this one basically from _[Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/FPWS_CH01.pdf),_ p. 10.

Comment: @benkovitz I think you're confusing "non-side-effecting" with "referentially transparent"?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Thanks! Indeed I wasn't distinguishing them. I've been scolded repeatedly by functional-programming advocates that creating objects that are identical but not `.equal` is a side-effect, and I see merit in the idea. Indeed object identity has sometimes fouled up determinism in my Scala programs. Is there some convention that creating objects not even intended to stay `.equal` [doesn't count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151616/do-the-mutable-collection-empty-methods-violate-scalas-zero-argument-naming-con/31151649?noredirect=1#comment50341805_31156148) as a side-effect?

Answer (score 1):

It's all a bit of a mess on the JVM.

In the presence of operations like eq/ne and System.identityHashCode, even creating a new ***immutable*** object has observable side-effects (namely increasing some counter deep in the bowels of the JVM so that the next object will have a different reference hashCode). So in JVM land, a function that does nothing except returning a new object is considered as side-effect free as you can get. If the object returned is mutable, referential transparency goes out of the window anyway, even though the function that *produces* the mutable object itself is considered side-effect free.

If you are really pedantic about it, there are ***no*** side-effect free functions on the JVM that return non-primitives.

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable._
scala> SortedSet.empty[Int] eq SortedSet.empty[Int]
res4: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Indeed I think there's really no way that anything in a real computer can be side-effect-free, since every operation takes time, every newly created object reduces the amount of available memory, etc. Not even Haskell can escape that. I figure there is some convention for which side-effects in Scala "count" and which "don't count". Since the objects created by `.empty` are not meant to stay `.equal`, I had guessed that _that_ would count as a side-effect. Apparently not?

Comment: I have not seen this spelled out explicitly anywhere, but my interpretation was that if you have a method that returns a mutable object, referential transparency obviously goes out the window. But the function that *creates* the mutable object is still considered to be "side effect free" because it does not do anything but produce a return value.

Methods that you should definitely not consider on the JVM if you want to argue about purity are definitely eq, ne, System.identityHashCode, and all other low level methods.